# PHP: How to get the error message of failed shell command?

Tags: php, bash, mysql

I execute the following command to make a database backup:

```
$exec = exec("mysqldump --opt 
                        --user=$database_user 
                        --password=$database_pass 
                        --host=$database_host 
                        $database_name > $output_filename", $out, $status);
```

To check if `mysqldump` failed I do:

```
if ($status == 0) {
   // OK
} else {
   // Error
   // How could I print the error message here ?
}
```

In case something goes wrong and `mysqldump` fails, how could I get the error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [proc_open](https://www.php.net/proc_open) (as also suggested by Emil). below is a somewhat more complete example of how to achieve what you want.

```
$exec_command = "mysqldump --opt 
                    --user=$database_user 
                    --password=$database_pass 
                    --host=$database_host 
                    $database_name"

$descriptorspec = array(
                       0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin pipe 
                       1 => array("file", $output_filename, "w"),  // stdout to file  
                       2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr pipe 
);
                    
$proc = proc_open($exec_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

fwrite($pipes[0], $input); //writing to std_in
fclose($pipes[0]);

$err_string = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]); //reading from std_err
fclose($pipes[2]); 

$return_val = proc_close($proc);
```

EDIT:

changed output to write to file

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open) if you want to read stderr. The example in the manual should get you going.

Comment: or redirect to stdout and extract it from `$output_filename`, since the dump wouldn't be valid in case of an error anyways.

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr (by convention, filehandle #2) to stdout (filehandle #1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shell_exec, append 2>&1 to the command, it will redirect STDERR to STDOUT.